# How to run Selenium tests (C#, .NET) with Firefox in headless mode on Jenkins running as Windows service

Tags: c#, firefox, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, headless-browser

I'm trying to set up Jenkins (version 2.117) and run automated tests using Selenium on the .NET stack in Windows 10 with Jenkins running as a Windows Service.

I'm attempting to use the Firefox web driver with Firefox 56, which supports a headless mode.

### Machine and Software

- Windows 10 pro
- Jenkins 2.117
- Selenium Webdriver (latest version as of this question)
- Firefox 56, 32 bit
- GeckoDriver v0.16.1
- Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise

### Selenium Test

```
[TestClass]
public class SeleniumTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    [TestProperty("Selenium", "Google")]
    public void GoToGoogle()
    {
        var options = new FirefoxOptions();
        options.AddArgument("-headless");
        var driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);

        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com");
        StringAssert.Contains(driver.PageSource, "Google");
    }
}
```

I can get a test working through Visual Studio, but fails during a build on Jenkins.

The command used to run the test:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\vstest.console.exe" C:\Jenkins\workspace\WorkSpaceName\Tests\bin\ContinuousIntegration\Tests.dll /tests:Google /logger:trx
```

### Jenkins Build Output

Here is the abbreviated output of the log for the build:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\vstest.console.exe" C:\Jenkins\workspace\WorkSpaceName\Tests\bin\ContinuousIntegration\Tests.dll /tests:Google /logger:trx 
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 15.6.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Starting test discovery, please wait...
1525798591265   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:58807
1525798592565   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser \\?\C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe with args ["-marionette", "-headless"]
*** You are running in headless mode.
1525798592835   addons.xpi  WARN    Error parsing extensions state: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80520012 (NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) [amIAddonManagerStartup.readStartupData]"  nsresult: "0x80520012 (NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)"  location: "JS frame :: resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm :: loadExtensionState :: line 1554"  data: no] Stack trace: loadExtensionState()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:1554 < getInstallState()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:1589 < checkForChanges()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:3109 < startup()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:2188 < callProvider()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:269 < _startProvider()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:739 < startup()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:906 < startup()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:3090 < observe()@jar:file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Mozilla%20Firefox/omni.ja!/components/addonManager.js:65
1525798593164   Marionette  INFO    Enabled via --marionette

###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x240058,name=PContent::Msg_SetPluginList) Channel error: cannot send/recv


###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24004C,name=PContent::Msg_GMPsChanged) Channel error: cannot send/recv


###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x150084,name=PBrowser::Msg_UpdateNativeWindowHandle) Channel error: cannot send/recv


###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x150078,name=PBrowser::Msg_Destroy) Channel error: cannot send/recv

###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv


###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv


###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv


###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv


###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv


###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv


###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv


###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv


###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv


###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv


###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv


###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv


###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv


###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv


###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv


###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv


###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv


###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv


###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv


###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv


###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv


###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv


###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv


###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv


###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24003F,name=PContent::Msg_LoadProcessScript) Channel error: cannot send/recv


###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24003F,name=PContent::Msg_LoadProcessScript) Channel error: cannot send/recv


###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x2400FC,name=PContent::Msg_AsyncMessage) Channel error: cannot send/recv


###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv


###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv


###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv


###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv


###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv


###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x2400FC,name=PContent::Msg_AsyncMessage) Channel error: cannot send/recv


###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv


###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv


###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x150084,name=PBrowser::Msg_UpdateNativeWindowHandle) Channel error: cannot send/recv


###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x150078,name=PBrowser::Msg_Destroy) Channel error: cannot send/recv


###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x150084,name=PBrowser::Msg_UpdateNativeWindowHandle) Channel error: cannot send/recv


###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x150078,name=PBrowser::Msg_Destroy) Channel error: cannot send/recv

1525798595876   addons.productaddons    WARN    Failed downloading via XHR, status: 0, reason: error
Failed   GoToGoogle
Error Message:
 Test method SeleniumTest.GoToGoogle threw exception: 
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:58807/session timed out after 60 seconds. ---> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: The operation has timed out.
Stack Trace:
    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.MakeHttpRequest(HttpRequestInfo requestInfo)
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.MakeHttpRequest(HttpRequestInfo requestInfo)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver..ctor(FirefoxOptions options)
   at StateOfMichigan.DisabilityServices.BusinessResources.Tests.UnitTests.SeleniumTest.GoToGoogle() in C:\Jenkins\workspace\MiBRS-22944-02\Tests\UnitTests\SeleniumTest.cs:line 16


Total tests: 1. Passed: 0. Failed: 1. Skipped: 0.
Test Run Failed.
Test execution time: 1.0295 Minutes
```

When browsing to the URL it mentions in the log output (http://localhost:58807/session) I get the following response:

```
{
  "value": {
    "error": "unknown command",
    "message": "GET /session did not match a known command",
    "stacktrace": "stack backtrace:\n   0:           0x489f6f - <no info>\n   1:           0x48ad59 - <no info>\n   2:           0x43a15d - <no info>\n   3:           0x42ec0f - <no info>\n   4:           0x423c30 - <no info>\n   5:           0x4078fa - <no info>\n   6:           0x6bc939 - <no info>\n   7:           0x415d0d - <no info>\n   8:           0x6b6e43 - <no info>\n   9:     0x7fff56fe8364 - BaseThreadInitThunk"
  }
}
```

Now the response above could be due to the browser issuing a `GET` request instead of a `POST`.

### Jenkins Service Properties

I've tried several iterations of configs for the Jenkins service:

#### Default Configuration

1. Using "Local System" account
2. No interaction with desktop

Result: Same as above

#### Tweaked Local System account

1. Using "Local System" account
2. Allow service to interact with desktop is check marked

Result: Same as above

#### Using local "Jenkins" user

Result: An exception that it couldn't find the active directory BEAN during the initialization phase

#### Using my Active Directory User

1. My own user and password
2. I have admin privileges on the machine

Result: Same as the original problem above

**How can I run Selenium tests in Firefox headless mode when running Jenkins as a Windows Service?**

---

**Update 1:** Looks like there might be an issue with my version of Firefox (v56) or GeckoDriver (v0.16.1) Switching to Chrome 66 and ChromeDriver 2.38.552522 seems to be working fine.

Comment: Can you notch up the geckodriver version and see if it helps? Comparing chromedriver and geckodriver working is like comparing apple and oranges, doesn't help

Comment: @TarunLalwani: We haven't updated the GeckoDriver in a while. I think the basic thing this proves is that running tests in headless mode *does* work when running Jenkins as a windows service. I think there's just something wrong with the combo of Firefox and GeckoDriver, like you mentioned.

Comment: @TarunLalwani: Just updated my question. We are on GeckoDriver 0.16.1 currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was new to Selenium and doesn't realize the version of GeckoDriver I was using was or of date compared to my version of Firefox. Updating GeckoDriver (now called Firefox driver) solved the problem.

If you think you have the right way driver, check your browser version. Modern browser vendors have automatic updates enabled. Either disable that feature and suffer the consequences of unpatched security vulnerabilities or just periodically check that the web driver is up to date.